# Why google doesnt index my single page app properly?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, single-page-application, googlebot, google-crawlers

Since some time google [officially depreceated ajax crawling scheme](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) they came up with back in 2009 so I decided to get rid of generating snapshots in phantomJS for _escaped_fragment and rely on google to render my single page app like a modern browser and discover its content. [They describe it in here](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html). But now I seem to have a problem.

Google indexed my page (at least I can see in webmastertools it has) but when using webmastertools I look at `google index-->content keywords` it shows non processed content of my angularJS templates only and names of my  binded variable names e.g. `{{totalnewprivatemessagescount}}` etc. The keywords do not contain words that should should be generated by ajax calls when Javascript executes so e.g. `fighter` is not even in there and it should be all over the place.

Now, when I use `Crawl-->Fetch as google-->Fetch and render` the snapshot  what google bot sees is very much the same as what user sees and is clearly generated using Javascript. The Fetch HTML tab though shows only source without being processed using JS which I'm guessing is fine.

Now my question is why google didn't index my website properly? Is there anything I implemented incorrectly somewhere? The website is live at https://www.fightersconnect.com and thanks for any advice.